# Dependent/Cascading Dropdowns in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia, dropdown

I'd like to create dependent dropdowns in Aurelia.

What I mean by dependent dropdowns is if you click an item in the first dropdown, then the options in the second dropdown are filtered down based on what you click. If you look at my js-fiddle, you'll notice that if you select Toyota in the first dropdown, the second one populates with Toyota car models (Corolla, Camry, etc.). If you select Honda in the first dropdown, the second one populates itself with Honda models (Accord, Civic, etc.). You get the idea.

It is very simple and requires very little code to do this in Angular and I was wondering if doing this in Aurelia is also simple and straightforward. I wasn't able to find much as far as resources on how to do this in Aurelia. The fiddle below demonstrates exactly what I would like to accomplish (except I'd like to do it in Aurelia, not Angular, of course). Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

https://jsfiddle.net/nhunt3/wjvvjwzx/

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
My Cars
<br />
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Make</td>
      <td>Model</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="car in myCars track by car.uid">
      <td>
        <select ng-model="car.MakeUID" ng-options="make.uid as make.name for make in makes" />
      </td>

      <td>
        <select
        ng-model="car.ModelUID"
        ng-options="model.uid as model.name for model in models | filter: { parentID: car.MakeUID } : true" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>   
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
// the main (app) module
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.makes = [
        {name:'Toyota', uid:1},
        {name:'Honda', uid:2},
        {name:'Ford', uid:3}
    ];

  $scope.models = [
            {name:'Yaris', uid:1, parentID:1},
        {name:'Corolla', uid:2, parentID:1},
        {name:'Camry', uid:3, parentID:1},
        {name:'Highlander', uid:4, parentID:1},
        {name:'Accord', uid:5, parentID:2},
        {name:'Civic', uid:6, parentID:2},
        {name:'Pilot', uid:7, parentID:2},
        {name:'Focus', uid:8, parentID:3},
        {name:'Fiesta', uid:9, parentID:3},
        {name:'Fusion', uid:10, parentID:3},
        {name:'F-150', uid:10, parentID:3}
    ];

  $scope.myCars = [
        {uid:1, MakeUID:1, ModelUID:2},
        {uid:2, MakeUID:1, ModelUID:3},
        {uid:3, MakeUID:3, ModelUID:8}
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For other users that find this thread:

app.html

```
<template>
  <require from="./filter"></require>
  <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Make</td>
      <td>Model</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr repeat.for="car of myCars">
      <td>
        <select value.bind="car.MakeUID" change.delegate="resetModel(car)">
          <option value="0">select one of ...</option>
          <option repeat.for="make of makes" model.bind="make.uid">${make.name}</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select value.bind="car.ModelUID">
          <option value="0">select one of ...</option>
          <option repeat.for="model of models | filter:'parentID':car.MakeUID" model.bind="model.uid">${model.name}</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr> 
  </tbody>
</template>
```

app.js

```
export class App { 
    makes = [
        {name:'Toyota', uid:1},
        {name:'Honda', uid:2},
        {name:'Ford', uid:3}
    ];

    models = [
        {name:'Yaris', uid:1, parentID:1},
        {name:'Corolla', uid:2, parentID:1},
        {name:'Camry', uid:3, parentID:1},
        {name:'Highlander', uid:4, parentID:1},
        {name:'Accord', uid:5, parentID:2},
        {name:'Civic', uid:6, parentID:2},
        {name:'Pilot', uid:7, parentID:2},
        {name:'Focus', uid:8, parentID:3},
        {name:'Fiesta', uid:9, parentID:3},
        {name:'Fusion', uid:10, parentID:3},
        {name:'F-150', uid:10, parentID:3}
    ];

    myCars = [
        {uid:1, MakeUID:1, ModelUID:2},
        {uid:2, MakeUID:1, ModelUID:3},
        {uid:3, MakeUID:3, ModelUID:8}
    ];

    resetModel(car) {
      car.ModelUID = 0;
    }
}
```

filter.js

```
export class FilterValueConverter {
  toView(array, propertyName, filter_on) {
    return array.filter(i => i[propertyName] == filter_on);
  }
}
```

**old answer**

I think this does the same as your Angular code in Aurelia:

```
<template>
  <require from="./filter"></require>
  <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Make</td>
      <td>Model</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr repeat.for="car of myCars">
      <td>
        <select value.bind="car.MakeUID" ref="selected_car">
          <option repeat.for="make of makes" value.bind="make.uid">${make.name}</option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <td>
        <select value.bind="car.ModelUID">
          <option repeat.for="model of models | filter:'parentID':selected_car.value">${model.name}</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr> 
  </tbody>
</template>
```

And you also need this filter:

```
export class FilterValueConverter {
  toView(array, propertyName, filter_on) {
    return array.filter(i => i[propertyName] == filter_on);
  }
}
```

https://gist.run/?id=91b23375e0b73afe7f21825f67cfeabf

Comment: Thanks, Eric! This is great! There are a couple minor features that mine has that yours doesn't, but I'm sure I can figure them out. (1) When you select a make in mine, the model selects blank instead of the first model. (2) when my page loads, it shows myCars, which is Toyota Corolla, Toyota Camry, & Ford Focus. Yours just shows Toyota Yaris all the way down. But like i said that's minor and you got nearly all of it. Thanks a ton! I'll give it a couple days to see if there are any better answers then I'll accept yours.

Comment: I tried to upvote your answer but it says i can't upvote until my reputation is higher.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I realize that the myCars array not getting selected is actually very major. MyCars is what would be coming from a database. And the values from the database would need to display on the screen on the page load. This is critical and I don't think I can accept an answer that doesn't have that. I think I may be part of the way there though. If you replace your first td in the app.html of your gist with the below (I added model.bind="make.uid" in the options tag), then the makes show up on page load...I just can't get the models to show up.

Comment: <td>
        <select value.bind="car.MakeUID" ref="selected_car">
          <option/>
          <option repeat.for="make of makes" model.bind="make.uid">${make.name}</option>
        </select>
      </td>

Comment: Sorry I assumed at first you wanted to know how to reference elements

Answer (score 2):

I finished your solution for you, but you gave me a very critical start on it. I removed an unnecessary ref in your make td and added a couple model.binds and changed what your filter matched on.

See my finalized gist which I forked from yours.

https://gist.run/?id=e0b9c401370a954b594ad2415d983099

Comment: Just did the same a few minutes back :-), was traveling back home in the time between the last edit and this :-) There still is a small issue. Try selecting toyata highlander and then ford, then it should reset.

Comment: I am not sure if this can be fixed only from the html, but it can be fixed if the car from the db can be transformed in a js class, with get and setters. That as soon as you set car, reset model.

Comment: See latest revision of this gist: https://gist.run/?id=91b23375e0b73afe7f21825f67cfeabf that fixes the above issue, still you need to add code to the js for that.

Comment: That's an interesting behavior of my gist...and only happens sometimes...weird...I'll look into that tomorrow and see if I can't find a better fix. Your reset function is definitely a good fix for now though. Thanks again for the help.